# How to increase the "Max tasks per node" in Azure batch?

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I have an Azure batch account and I'd like to increase the "Max tasks per node" property on my pool. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you can only do this at the time of pool creation. Please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-parallel-node-tasks#enable-parallel-task-execution) for more information.